# Error while assigning array value to variable in apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have captured a data range in an array. My column 3 of the array  remains constant and only my row needs to increment while assigning this value to a variable matchindex. While assigning the value to a variable I am getting an **error** stating

> 'Çannot read property 3 from undefined'.

I am getting this error on the line while assigning `matchindex = data[i+2][3]`.

Can somebody please explain what is going wrong?

Below is my script

```
function testrange() {
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var i=0;
  var temp1 =2;
  var temp2 =2;
  var startrow;
  var endrow;
  var matchindex;
  var ssVillage = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('VillageName'),true);  
  var range = ssVillage.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var lastcol = ssVillage.getLastColumn();


for (i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
  matchindex = data[i+2][3];

  temp1 = matchindex;
  if(temp1 !== temp2) {   

   // spreadsheet.setNamedRange(ssVillage.getRange("B"+startrow).getValue(),ssVillage.getRange("A"+startrow +":A"+endrow).activate() );    
      spreadsheet.setNamedRange(data[i+2][startrow],ssVillage.getRange("A"+startrow +":A"+endrow).activate() );            
      if (i+2 == matchindex) {
       startrow = (i+2);
       endrow = i+2;
      }      
      else {
        endrow = i+2;
      }
    }

  else {
    if (i+2 == matchindex) {
       startrow = (i+2);
       endrow = i+2;
      }      
      else {
        endrow = i+2;
      }
  }
  temp2 = matchindex;

  }
}
```

Comment: so basically that value doesn't exist in array. did you check your array ?

Comment: yes..Array shows the value when i checked. What i am trying to do is define namedranges for col A, based on col B values. Also i get an error where i define the namedrange. When i use logger.log to check outside the for loop the values are shown correctly

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating in for loop from i=0 to the length of array ( say L). In last 2 iterations, the value of `(i+2)` will be `L`, `L+1`. And definitely there will not be an index equal to length of array or more than that.
Since L and L+1 index does not exist, value of `data[i+2]` will be `undefined` hence getting the error.

> 'Çannot read property 3 from undefined'.

Comment: Thanks Waqar. This explains it. Do you have a suggestion to offer to tackle it?